# Fixing keefox on ubuntu

Tags: firefox, keepass

Keefox used to be working, but it stopped connecting to keepass from one day to the other. I get the message from keefox:

> To upgrade KeeFox: 1) Copy the KeePassRPC.plgx file to the plugins
>   subdirectory inside the directory that contains your KeePass
>   installation (e.g. ~/KeePass/plugins where ~ represents your home
>   directory)
>
> 2) Restart Firefox

I've done both steps. What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time. If you're certain you have KeePassRPC.plgx up to date and in the right location, you next need to clear Keepass's plugin cache.

Launch Keepass and go to `Tools → Plugins`. Near the bottom you should see a section called "Plugin Cache"; click the `Clear` button, exit the dialogue, then **exit** Keepass (make sure it isn't just 'closed' to the tray) and open it again.

Once you've restarted Keepass you can restart Firefox. KeeFox should work at that point.